# MySQL: Why would an `ID` column be defined with `NOT NULL` if using `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Tags: mysql

I was reading somewhere that adding the `AUTO_INCREMENT` will allow the `id` column to automatically generate sequential numbers starting from 1. However, in that case, it seems that there is no need to define `NOT NULL` and `UNIQUE`. Why is it that I still see many examples online using `NOT NULL` with `AUTO_INREMENT`, when creating a table?

Comment: While the `NULL` thing may not be obvious, of course you need the key to be `UNIQUE`. The number is also not guaranteed to be sequential.

Answer (score 0):

[Per the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html), if you assign null values to an auto_id which is defined as not-null, it will replace null with the next sequential value. As ID is likely your primary key (or part of your key), it shouldn't ever take null values.

Also, [per this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/870863/2), if you don't specify that it should be non-null, MySQL will supply this for you.

Comment: Thank you for your time... However, I am still slightly confused. So you mean to say that if `NOT NULL` is specified you can simply provide `NULL` and the next sequential number will be used. But doesn't the `AUTO_INCREMENT` do that anyway? Also, towards the end of your answer, you seem to say that if you do not add `NOT NULL` specifically the system will do it for you anyway... And that is what I expected from the get go... So what is the point then? My question is really about why people still bother to add `NOT NULL` if the system adds it anyway?

Comment: From a different answer: "As a matter of good design, if a column requires a value in order to properly function, it should be declared NOT NULL." That's why people bother, because good and bad practice. It's like asking why people use OOP design patterns when the whole project fits in a single file with goto's and globals.

Comment: @Grateful If MySQL is adding it automatically, how do you know whether people are specifying it themselves, or it is being supplied by MySQL :-). (People recycle table designs, then run `show create mytable`...)
As Dan indicates, it is probably a good idea to include it, if only so users who aren't familiar with the feature understand from your code that this field will never be null.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after re-reading documentation it seems that if `NOT NULL` is defined... When inserting values, one may use the value `NULL` to automatically assign the next sequential number. If `NOT NULL` is not defined, then one may only use the value 0 to assign the next sequential number. Also, it should be noted that `UNIQUE` doesn't need to be defined because ID's are usually used in conjunction with `PRIMARY KEY` which achieves the same.

Comment: It doesn't need to be explicitly defined, but it MUST be defined as not-null. (Try to create a table with an `auto_increment` field which doesn't show `NOT NULL` when you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)